# Права доступа в Shared Folder на VMware

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware

На Windows 10 стоит VMware на которой установлена Ubuntu 16.01.
Также через VMware настроена общая папка.
Проблема такая:
Если я создаю файл на Ubuntu в Shared Folder:

```
$ ls -l 1.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 796 Jan 22 19:07 1.txt
```

причем поменять через `chmod` не получается. Команда `chmod -x` просто игнорируется.

```
$ ls -l 1.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 796 Jan 22 19:07 1.txt
$ chmod -x 1.txt
$ ls -l 1.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 796 Jan 22 19:07 1.txt
```

Можно ли решить эту проблему?

Comment: А с `sudo` пробовали?

Comment: Да через `sudo`  тоже пробовал, команда просто игнорируется, если переместить файл в домашнюю директорию то все работает